# Why has my auto-generated profile picture changed?

Tags: discussion

My auto-generated profile picture was green, it's now blue and a different pattern.

Pretty sure this has changed at some point today, but only just noticed.

Not a problem, but intrigued to know why it's happened?

What drives the colour/pattern?

---

**Edit after submission of question**

OK, so the picture is *still* green on the panel under the question, but on my header bar it's definitely blue!

[image]

Comment: Ah, "avatar", that's the keyword that I couldn't think of... thanks @yellowantphil